# Clojure - Calling a function on a vector of vectors

Tags: clojure

I have a vector `[[1 2 3 4] [5 6]]` and I want to call the function `double` on this vector to get `[[1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0] [5.0 6.0]]`

I can do `(mapv (fn [x] (mapv double x)) [[1 2 3 4] [5 6]])` which will give me what I want

I was wondering if there are any better/faster ways of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: With specter: `(transform [ALL ALL] double [[1 2 3 4] [5 6]])`

Comment: or `clojure/walk`: `(clojure.walk/prewalk #(if (number? %) (double %) %) data)` , it also allows you to transform collections with arbitrary depth

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that I'd necessarily call this "better", but it is my personal preference to use `for` whenever I have to nest calls to map.  I just find it more readable personally.

```
(def vecs [[1 2 3 4] [5 6]])

(for [r vecs] (for [x r] (double x)))
```

The data returns in a list, I'm assuming it's not particular important that you keep it in a vector.  If you do, then it gets a little less readable and I might prefer your approach.

```
(vec (for [r vecs] (vec (for [x r] (double x)))))
```

Comment: ... or, with `(defmacro forv [& stuff] (list 'vec (cons 'for stuff)))`, just `(forv [r vecs] (forv [x r] (double x)))`.